# Why does female's age of puberty inform on mating system?

Tags: evolution, sex, sexual-selection, life-history

Reading from [Does increased calorie intake cause increase in libido in humans?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48807/does-increased-calorie-intake-cause-increase-in-libido-in-humans), @AlexStone says:

> I'm aware that humans have a dual mating strategy - somewhere between pair bond and casual mating. There are a number of physical measures to indicate this - such as sexual dimorphism between male and female, sperm counts and tested size, as well as age of puberty of females.

- How does the age of puberty of females can inform us on the mating strategy?
- Why does the observed age of puberty of females suggests a "dual mating strategy"?